# Can't save plots to white background png

Tags: r, plot

I have this R code to capture plots, and save as PNG

```
 fun1 <- function() {
 
  plots<- vector(2, mode='list')
  g_clustDend <- plotDendroAndColors(net$dendrograms[[1]], mergedColors[net$blockGenes[[1]]],
                                     "Module colors",
                                     dendroLabels = FALSE, hang = 0.03,
                                     addGuide = TRUE, guideHang = 0.05)
  plots[[1]]<- recordPlot()
  
  g_heatmap <- labeledHeatmap(Matrix = moduleTraitCor,
                              xLabels = names(groupTrait),
                              yLabels = names(MEs),
                              ySymbols = names(MEs),
                              colorLabels = FALSE,
                              colors = greenWhiteRed(50),
                              textMatrix = textMatrix,
                              setStdMargins = FALSE,
                              cex.text = 0.5,
                              zlim = c(-1,1),
                              main = paste("Module-trait relationships"))
  plots[[2]]<- recordPlot()
  graphics.off()
  
  print("Printing plot to png")
  png(file.path(wd, 'dendro.png'), width=4, height=5, unit='in', res=300)
  print(plots[[1]])
  dev.off()
  
  png(file.path(wd, 'correlation.png', , width=4, height=5, unit='in', res=300))
  print(plots[[2]])
  dev.off()
}
```

what I got is a transparent background png as below
[image]

I was trying to make the background as white, but failed with

```
par(bg='white')
```

So how can I do this correctly?

Comment: Add `bg = "white"` to the `png()` functions.

Comment: @LeroyTyrone thanks for suggestion but this doesn't work. Still transparent background

Comment: Works in base R, both inside `png()` and as `par(bg = white)`. Found [this post](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/698) regarding the `ComplexHeatmap` package that indicates earlier versions did not support white backgrounds for .png files. Maybe the same thing is happening for you?  Worst case is output to .jpeg obviously. Sorry I couldn't be of more help than that.